# Как в ffmpeg отключить AnnexB при кодировании потока с live-источника?

Tags: ffmpeg

В энкодере libx264, который используется ffmpeg, есть параметр `x264_param_t::b_annexb`.
Какие аргументы командной строки ffmpeg управляют им?

Comment: Если ничего не путаю, по умолчанию он вроде и не должен использоваться. В какой формат (контейнер) вы кодируете?

Comment: @andreymal, в TS

Comment: Формат MPEG-TS требует обязательного использования AnnexB, ffmpeg включает его автоматически и отключить его технически невозможно